# Dynamically updating a pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am receiving data every second and I need to update the same pie chart with each data received. I read some forums and have a code in place. However, currently with each recieving values, I am getting another pie chart i.e. the previous pie chart value is not getting refreshed. I want to refresh the same pie chart value

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
labels=['a','b']
def animate(i):
    nums=[x1,x2]
    ax.clear()
    ax1.pie(nums, labels=labels, 
                    autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
            
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

The value of `x1` and `x2` keeps changing. All this is inside a `for loop` that listens new data arising in `x1` and `x2`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the snippet. This will update graph in every 2 seconds.

You can call `plt.pause(2)` to both draw the new data and it runs the GUI's event loop

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
labels=['a','b']
for i in range(10):    
    nums=[random.randint(5,10),random.randint(5,10)]
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.pie(nums, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
    plt.pause(2)
plt.draw()
```

Comment: I tried the same snippet. However, it is not updating the pie chart. It shows a piechart, and then the pie chart remain static. Can you check that once?

Comment: The values are getting changed.. Even the percentage too @Nidutt .Maybe change `plt.pause(1)` so that pie chart will update quickly

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any experience with pie chart animation, but here's a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358835/pie-chart-animation-in-python) that I found helpful.

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs']
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0) 

def animate(i):
    new_sizes = []
    new_sizes = random.sample(sizes, len(sizes))
    print(new_sizes)
    ax.clear()
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.pie(new_sizes, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140) 

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, repeat=False) 

plt.show()
```

[image]