# Animating pie chart using FuncAnimation showing last frame only

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to use Matplotlib's FuncAnimation function to update a pie chart and make a gif. I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670477/animate-a-pie-chart-column-by-column-using-a-dataframe) and it didn't get much traction. So Here is my dataset, a list of pandas series which I'll refer to as `numbers`, shown simplified below:

```
[[6.166, 5.976, 3.504, 7.104, 5.14],
 [7.472, 5.888, 3.264, 6.4825, 7.168],
 [7.5716, 9.936, 3.6, 8.536, 2.808],
 [2.604, 2.296, 0.0, 6.144, 4.836],
 [7.192, 4.932, 0.0, 6.016, 8.808],
 [7.192, 5.5755, 3.694, 9.376, 9.108],
 [7.63616, 5.912, 3.968, 6.672, 3.192],
 [3.41049, 5.44, 4.004, 7.212, 3.6954],
 [4.3143, 6.364, 3.584, 7.44, 5.78],
 [4.992, 3.9692, 4.272, 0.0, 2.528]]
```

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
colors = ["yellow", "red", "purple", "blue", "green"]
explode = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
labels = ["DM", "Bard", "Warlock", "Paladin", "Ranger"]
z = [0,0,0,0,0]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def update(num):
    
    ax.axis('equal')
    global z
    for x in range(0,10):
        z += numbers[x]
        z = z.tolist()
        
        
        
    ax.pie(z, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, 
            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)

    ax.set_title(sum(z))    
    
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(10), repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

Based on this output only the totals are being displayed in the final frame. There is no intermediary animation going on. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358835/pie-chart-animation-in-python) and answer but I cannot figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the `ax` at the beginning of `update`, besides I think this part

```
for x in range(0,10):
    z += numbers[x]
    z = z.tolist()
```

is incorrect. Try the code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

numbers = [[6.166, 5.976, 3.504, 7.104, 5.14],
 [7.472, 5.888, 3.264, 6.4825, 7.168],
 [7.5716, 9.936, 3.6, 8.536, 2.808],
 [2.604, 2.296, 0.0, 6.144, 4.836],
 [7.192, 4.932, 0.0, 6.016, 8.808],
 [7.192, 5.5755, 3.694, 9.376, 9.108],
 [7.63616, 5.912, 3.968, 6.672, 3.192],
 [3.41049, 5.44, 4.004, 7.212, 3.6954],
 [4.3143, 6.364, 3.584, 7.44, 5.78],
 [4.992, 3.9692, 4.272, 0.0, 2.528]]
numbers = np.array(numbers)

colors = ["yellow", "red", "purple", "blue", "green"]
explode = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
labels = ["DM", "Bard", "Warlock", "Paladin", "Ranger"]
z = np.array([0,0,0,0,0]).astype(np.float)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

def update(num):
    
    global z
    
    ax.clear()
    ax.axis('equal')     
    z += numbers[num]  
    pie = ax.pie(z, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, 
                 autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
    ax.set_title(sum(z))    
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(10), repeat=False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=1)
```

the output is

[image: output]

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do and I'm very grateful for your help. I'm so glad this is done without that for loop, it was driving me nuts. Could you help explain to me how `num` works in the update function? After looking at the documentation I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @m00saca You're welcome :) `num` is the argument that `animation.FuncAnimation` passes to the function `update`. Since `frames=range(10)`, `animation.FuncAnimation` will pass 10 integers (the indices of the frames) to the function `update`.

Comment: wow, okay so that `num` argument is like an iterator for each item in the list?

Comment: @m00saca `num` is not an iterator, it is `FuncAnimation` will pass the items in `frames` iteratively to the function `update`. :)

Comment: @meTchailkovsky okay got it, again thanks a lot for the help and explanation.

Comment: @meTchailkovsky I did notice that this gif isn't showing the first frame. Any idea why?

Comment: @m00saca I don’t know, since the index of the first frame is 0 (you can print num in the function update to see this), the first row of the array numbers will be added to the zero array z. Therefore, the first frame should be correspond to the first row of the array numbers.

Comment: @meTchailkovsky thanks for the reply. I have done what you suggested in trying to figure out the behavior of `num`. I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743729/funcanimation-being-called-too-many-times

Comment: @m00saca you’re welcome, I didn’t notice this behavior before, thank you! :) There is an answer to your new post, looks like it will resolve the issue.